# How to get the byte array from the file path in the array from?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to get the byte array from file path to upload the image. But the byte array in the form of array.How do i get the byte array. I have followed the following steps but could not found the solutions.

I have tried the following code but does not work.

```
byte []buffer=new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
    int read;
    while ((read=fis.read(buffer))!=-1){
        os.write(buffer,0,read);
    }
    fis.close();
    os.close();
```

It return the byte array object but i need the array. When i used Array.toString(bytearray) it return in the string form but i need the array form. Please help me how can i do this.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc? `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`?

Comment: @user207421 this does not work

Comment: 'Does not work' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

convert the bytes to file, see below code.

```
InputStream is = Context.openFileInput(someFileName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];

while ((int bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) { 
    bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}

byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

or

```
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

Comment: by using the above code i get the the  byte array like this:- "byteArray": "[B@b0b6b8c", but i need in the the array.

Comment: you want a int[] array?

Comment: @RishikeshRahi That's the result of calling `toString()` on the byte array, directly or indirectly, e.g. via `String.valueOf()` or `print()` or `println()`. Solution: don't.

Comment: @gauravgajjar yes

Comment: public int[] convert(byte buf[]) {
   int intArr[] = new int[buf.length / 4];
   int offset = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
      intArr[i] = (buf[3 + offset] & 0xFF) | ((buf[2 + offset] & 0xFF) << 8) |
                  ((buf[1 + offset] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((buf[0 + offset] & 0xFF) << 24);  
   offset += 4;
   }
   return intArr;
}

Comment: try this code to convert in to int array

Comment: @RishikeshRahi If you want an `int[]` array why do both your title and your question ask for a `byte[]` array?

Comment: @gauravgajjar it still return like [I@d6028e7.

Comment: you print a array in log?

Comment: yes i do that but it still like above

Comment: i need like this but not in string it should be in array."byteArray": "[-109, -75, 90, -103, -101, 44, 118, 38, 112, -4, 35, -107, -123, -66, -69, -54, 106, -85, -40, 86, 20, 90, 42, -18, 54, -13, -45, 39, 42, -73, 59, -8, -86]"

Comment: @RishikeshRahi (1) You haven't answered my question; (2) 'not in string' is meaningless. You've already been told why you're getting what you're getting. [`java.util.Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-byte:A-) will produce exactly the output you want. But only if you *call* it.